# Android - determining why SMS sending failed

Tags: android, sms

I have an reminder app which will send an SMS to notifiy the user that their reminder time has passed. This works well. However, I've been testing what happens when the phone has been asleep and missed an reminder.

I'm using `AlarmManager` to set up alarms to correspond to reminder times. My logging shows that the alarm went off when the phone reboots and an attempt to send an SMS happens, but the SMS is never received.

So the question is, is there a way to debug why an SMS is not sent?

My current code sets up a ContentObserver when an alarm event occurs:

```
    private void registerToListenForSentSMS()
{
    MessageSentListener smsObeserver = new MessageSentListener(new Handler());
    ContentResolver contentResolver = TheEveryOtherAlarmAppApplication.getAppContext().getContentResolver();
    contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), true, smsObeserver);
}
```

MessageSentListener gets notified that *some* SMS event happened:

```
public class MessageSentListener extends ContentObserver
{

public MessageSentListener(Handler handler)
{
    super(handler);
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
{
    super.onChange(selfChange);

    Log.d(Constants.ALARM_APP_LOG_TAG, "Something happend");
    ContentResolver contentResolver = AlarmAppApplication.getAppContext().getContentResolver();

    contentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(this);
}
}
```

But this could be caused by SMS events unrelated to my app. Anyway, it doesn't really get me closer to a solution - I would like to know what went wrong when *nothing* happens!

In the event that an alarm SMS is not sent, I would be able to either resend or use some other notification method such as email etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BroadcastReceiver to check is sms sent or not if not what is the problem

```
 val TAG = "TRACK_SMS_STATUS"

    private fun sendSMS(phoneNumber: String, message: String) {
    val send = "SMS_SENT"
    val delivered = "SMS_DELIVERED"
    val sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0,
        Intent(send), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    val deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0,
        Intent(delivered),  PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(arg0: Context?, arg1: Intent?) {
            val bundle: Bundle? = arg1?.extras
            when (resultCode) {
                AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SMS sent")
                }
                SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE -> {
                    Log.d(TAG,   "Generic failure")

                }
                SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No service")
                }
                SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Null PDU")
                }
                SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Radio off")
                }
            }
        }
    }, IntentFilter(send))

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(arg0: Context?, arg1: Intent?) {
            when (resultCode) {
                AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SMS delivered")
                }
                AppCompatActivity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SMS not delivered")
                }
            }
        }
    }, IntentFilter(delivered))
    val sms = SmsManager.getDefault()
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI)
}
```